# How to define disk in gcp in a regional scope?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP and trying use Java SDK to create a template.

I am using the following code snippet and after executing it, I'm getting this error: "*Disk must be in a regional scope*".

```
InstanceTemplate instanceTemplate = new InstanceTemplate();
AttachedDisk attachedDisk = new AttachedDisk();
attachedDisk.setSource("");
List<AttachedDisk> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(attachedDisk);
InstanceProperties instanceProperties = new InstanceProperties();
instanceProperties.setDisks(list);
instanceProperties.setMachineType("e2");

List<NetworkInterface> listNetworkInterface = new ArrayList<>();
NetworkInterface networkInterface = new NetworkInterface();
networkInterface.setName("myname");
networkInterface.setNetwork("");
networkInterface.setSubnetwork("");
listNetworkInterface.add(networkInterface);
instanceProperties.setNetworkInterfaces(listNetworkInterface);

instanceTemplate
    .setName("instance-template-1")
    .setDescription("desc")
    .setProperties(instanceProperties);
compute.instanceTemplates().insert("", instanceTemplate).execute();
```

I am not able to understand what i am missing here.

Comment: See if `.attachDisk` function works. Items to keep in mind are that the disk must be pre-created. It cannot be created during instance creation. And, the disk must be created in the same region as where you are creating the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first create the disk before you can attach it. It is not possible to create and attach a disk at the same time. Also check the disk and the [instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates#creating_a_new_instance_template) should be in the same region.

To attach the disk, use the [compute.instances.attachDisk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/beta/instances/attachDisk) method and include the URL to the persistent disk that you’ve created.

If you are creating a [new template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instanceTemplates/insert#response-body) to update an existing instance group, your new instance template must use the same network or, if applicable, the same subnetwork as the original template.

After you create and attach a new disk to a VM, you must [format and mount](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/regional-persistent-disk#formatting) the disk, so that the operating system can use the available storage space.

**Note:** Zonal disks must be specified with bare names; zonal disks specified with a path (even a matching one) results in an "Disk must be in a regional scope" error.